# Google contacts api: the last id created

Tags: php, google-api, google-contacts-api

Is there a way to get the id of the new contact you just created using google api. I'm using [this code](https://gist.github.com/lovasoa/9547629) to create the contact.

Comment: Check this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428417/how-to-get-the-user-contactid-using-google-api-using-php) and this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) if it can help you.

Comment: Thank you so much.